# All google slide url parameters available?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

Where is the official documentation for the URL parameters/arguments?

There are things like /preview, /copy, /export,/htmlpresent #headings, ?something question mark, that I stumbled on tips and tricks articles on the web.

Where is the Official URL API that explains ALL of them?

Comment: Google Slides share most of the URL paramaters with Google Docs and Google Sheets. [Have a look at this response](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands/130655#130655) to find out available parameters for Docs.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this references contains all information and guidelines related to Google Slides API:
https://developers.google.com/slides

https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/overview

https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest

You could also add more details on what you are trying to look for so I assist you better